# How to select all from table where concat is user ids

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I want to select all from specific rows usin concat but my syntax fails without an error.

Here's what's I've done.

```
mysqli($con, "SELECT * 
              FROM table 
              WHERE uid = CONCAT (8, '', 7, '', 1)") 
              or die(mysqli_error($con));.
```

How do I select only from those ids with concat?

Answer (score 1):

1. what is `mysqli`? It should be variable `$mysqli`
2. you don´t call `query`, so `$mysqli->query`
3. I think you´re looking for `IN` instead of `CONCAT`, so `... WHERE uid IN (8, 7, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid IN (8,7,1)");

Answer (score 1):

CONCAT can take only two parameters as input. in your SQL 5 parameters are passed as arguments to CONCAT try using the below query it may work
SELECT * FROM table WHERE    uid = CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT (8, ''), 7), ''), 1)